# In Bash can I copy the last typed argument to the cursor position?

Tags: bash

Suppose I have the following in my terminal:

```
> cp my_file_name originals/#
```

Where the `#` represents the cursor.

Is there a key combination to insert `my_file_name` into the cursor position, so that I don't have to type it again? I'm aware of <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to get the last argument from the previous command, but I want the previous argument from the current command!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't `cp myfile orginals/` do precisely the same thing as `cp myfile originals/myfile`?

Comment: You're absolutely right - it's a poor example, but a simple example of what I want :) I need to do the same thing in situations where originals/ isn't clear enough.

Comment: I too wish there was an equivalent of Zsh's `copy-prev-shell-word` :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to cut the argument and store it in your clipboard, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to paste it again:

```
cp my_file_nameCtrl+W Ctrl+Y originals/Ctrl+Y
```

Answer (score 11):

One way of doing it is using [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion):

```
cp {,originals/}my_file_name
```

Comment: +1. Just spent 5 mins trying cp file{,/orig}. doh ! thx for posting this.

Answer (score 7):

**Complicated usage, but simpler setup:**

You can bind a keystroke (I'll use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>) to the `readline` `copy-backward-word` function and do this:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd>

That means:

- `digit-argument` `copy-backward-word` (copy the two preceding words)
- `yank` (paste)
- `backward-kill-word` (get rid of the extra word)

To bind the keystroke at the command line:

```
bind '"\C-q": copy-backward-word'
```

or add this to your `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\C-q": copy-backward-word
```

**Simpler usage, but more complicated setup:**

You can make that long keystroke sequence into a macro triggered by one keystroke (I'll use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd> here and make use of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd> binding from above):

At a shell prompt:

```
bind '"\eq": "\e2\C-q\C-y\e\C-h"'
```

or in your `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\eq": "\e2\C-q\C-y\e\C-h"
```

Remember, you'll also need to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd> as above.

Now to copy the word before the current one all you need to press is <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

```
    cp my_file_name originals/!#:1
```

!# is the current line, :1 is the first argument.

Comment: Wow, that is a good general tip that I never knew

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way, although I'm not certain why you are looking to do what you are trying to do, since the file name is implied in your cp command example (and would work as expected).

```
> F=my_file_name && cp $F Workspace/$F
```

This could be expanded out, also, to rename the file:

```
> F=my_file_name && cp $F Workspace/$F.new
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually need to do this in situations where the second use of the filename is required so my choice of using cp for the question was a poor choice.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

`cp my_file_name`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>`originals/`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>

But that doesn't work when you are already at the end of the line. Perhaps something similar might work though. (and with copy, not cut)

Edit: Try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>    — a bit of a messy solution though!

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\ej":"!#:$\e^"
```

`!#` is the current line, `:$` is the last word, and `\e^` is `history-expand-line`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is simple. Just add the following lined to your `.inputrc` file:

```
# File rename helper
"\em": "\C-w\C-y\C-y"
```

Don't forget to reload the session (or open a new tab) to apply the changes. After that, you can use <kbd>Alt-m</kbd> to copy the last "word".

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing the previous answers, I put the following in my ~/.inputrc file:

```
"\ej":"!#:1\e^"
```

`!#` is the current line,`:1` is the first argument, `\e^` is `history-expand-line`.

Then you just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to copy the first argument of the line:

```
mv file_name my_other_Ctrl+J
```

that is equivalent to:

```
mv file_name my_other_file_name
```